# Can not load a WMS services on QGIS

Tags: qgis, wms

Trying to load the service http://gis.ktimanet.gr/wms/ktbasemap/default.aspx
and receives the message
Could not understand the response. The wms provider said:
Could not get WMS capabilities: error occurred while parsing reference at line 5 column 179
This is probably due to an incorrect WMS Server URL.
Neither in http://gis.ktimanet.gr/wms/ktbasemap/default.aspx?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities
I have result.I never had a similar problem again with this service into something so simple

Answer (score 4):

The web site for the online user is not the same adress as for the WMS service.

Following the last link on the entrance page https://www.ktimanet.gr/CitizenWebApp/Entrance_Page.aspx to https://www.ktimanet.gr/CitizenWebApp/Orthophotographs_Page.aspx I found this address:

http://gis.ktimanet.gr/wms/wmsopen/wmsserver.aspx

which works in QGIS as WMS service.